# Why does ctags list the same entry twice?

Tags: vim, ctags

I run `ctags` from inside gvim like this:

```
:!ctags -R --c++-kinds=+p --fields=+iaS --extra=+q+f .
```

And then when trying to jump to a specific file (or tag):

```
:tjump pjsua.h
```

Every hit is listed twice

[image: tjump output]

What am I doing wrong?

OS and versions:

- Ubuntu 12.04
- Vim 7.3
- Exuberant Ctags 5.9~svn20110310

Comment: I haven't this issue. Make sure you haven't several tags files (check output of `:set tags?`) And, well, I recommend you not to generate your tags manually, but use plugin Indexer: http://goo.gl/EwILz , it provides painless automatic tags generation for whole project(s) and keeps tags up-to-date.

Comment: The output is `tags=~/mypath/.git/tags,./tags,./TAGS,tags,TAGS` and changing it to `tags` only solves the problem. So you are right. But I don't think I have changed the default settings so it seems a bit weird that it's wrong in the first place. Any ideas? By the way add you comment as answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Forgot to direct my post to you @DmitryFrank

Comment: Glad it helped. In my answer I also typed ideas about weird `tags` value, check it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer from comment: I haven't this issue. Make sure you haven't several tags files (check output of `:set tags?`)

By default `tags` has the value `./tags,tags`. If you have different one and you don't know where it was changed, type the following: `:verbose set tags?`, you will see the filename where it was changed.

And, well, I recommend you not to generate your tags manually, but use plugin [Indexer](http://goo.gl/EwILz), it provides painless automatic tags generation for whole project(s) and keeps tags up-to-date.

For detailed information, see the article: [Vim: convenient code navigation for your projects](http://dmitryfrank.com/articles/vim_project_code_navigation), which explains the usage of Indexer + Vimprj thoroughly.

Comment: Using `:verbose` was very helpful, didn't know about it. Turns out it was [fugitive](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive) that was setting the value.

Comment: Update: Removing fugitive gave me `tags=./tags,./TAGS,tags,TAGS` which seems to be default and it also gives me duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

If the code is on a volume formatted with FAT32 *tags* and *TAGS* will point to the same file.

```
$ ls -la tags TAGS
-rwx------ 1 user user 6848879 jun 28 09:31 tags
-rwx------ 1 user user 6848879 jun 28 09:31 TAGS
```